# Simplest way to auto-restart a JVM on StackOverflowError

Tags: error-handling, jvm, stack-overflow

It does not seem that there is a -XX option to restart a JVM on **StackOverflowError**. What is the simplest way to auto-restart a JVM when it gets a **StackOverflowError**?

Answer (score 4):

HotSpot JVM has built-in `-XX:AbortVMOnException=java.lang.StackOverflowError` option, but unfortunately this flag is available only in debug builds of JVM.

The working solution is to use [JVM TI agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) that will intercept all exceptions and abort the process whenever the exception belongs to the specified class. Here is an example of such agent.

```
#include <jvmti.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const char* fatal_error_class;

void JNICALL ExceptionCallback(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv* env, jthread thread,
                               jmethodID method, jlocation location, jobject exception,
                               jmethodID catch_method, jlocation catch_location) {
    char* class_name;
    jclass exception_class = env->GetObjectClass(exception);
    jvmti->GetClassSignature(exception_class, &class_name, NULL);
    class_name[strlen(class_name) - 1] = 0;

    if (strcmp(class_name + 1, fatal_error_class) == 0) {
        printf("Abort on fatal error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*)class_name);
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* unused) {
    if (options == NULL || options[0] == 0) {
        printf("Usage: -agentpath:/path/to/libabort.so=java/lang/StackOverflowError\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fatal_error_class = strdup(options);

    jvmtiEnv* jvmti;
    vm->GetEnv((void**)&jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);

    jvmtiCapabilities capabilities = {0};
    capabilities.can_generate_exception_events = 1;
    jvmti->AddCapabilities(&capabilities);

    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks = {0};
    callbacks.Exception = ExceptionCallback;
    jvmti->SetEventCallbacks(&callbacks, sizeof(callbacks));
    jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_EXCEPTION, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

How to compile it:

```
g++ -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux -fPIC -shared -olibabort.so abort.cpp
```

How to run:

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libabort.so=java/lang/StackOverflowError ...
```