# How to define multiple errors for -XX:AbortVMOnException

Tags: jvm

I am depending on libraries that hang for certain errors, which I cannot fix! The offenders are currently `StackOverflowError` and `OutOfMemoryError` but there might be more.

I am trying to upgrade the unrecoverable hang to an exit/abort. However, I cannot figure out how to pass multiple different errors to the `-XX:AbortVMOnException` as only the latest argument is active in:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:AbortVMOnException=java.lang.StackOverflowError -XX:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one value for `AbortVMOnException` option.

JVM does a [substring search](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/2a5e0dd3609d2fcbfa1898a093f45f72e83fdd9d/src/hotspot/share/utilities/exceptions.cpp#L541) when checking if the exception class matches `AbortVMOnException` value. E.g. `-XX:AbortVMOnException=Error` will cause the VM to abort on any throwable with `Error` in its name: `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, etc.

To add a custom callback on the desired exception types, you may use the JVM TI approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44790545/3448419). You'd only need to replace

```
if (strcmp(class_name + 1, fatal_error_class) == 0) {
```

with

```
if (strstr(fatal_error_class, class_name + 1) != NULL) {
```

and then it will be possible to specify multiple exceptions types that cause VM exit:

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libabort.so=java/lang/StackOverflowError,java/lang/OutOfMemoryError ...
```